# Hosting images with consistent link

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

here are the two links I got from the images I uploaded on Dropbox (Direct Links)

```html
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/99mfe2z2w7acvjt/12318297489hfsdkjfkjehiuhiuwhefwebgkjwebfw%20%281%29.jpg?dl=0

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/9l1e5017w5gcy44/12318297489hfsdkjfkjehiuhiuwhefwebgkjwebfw%20%282%29.jpg?dl=0
```

for you to see clearly what I meant I'd emphasize it below.
showing which part of the link is not "consistent"

https ://dl.dropbox.com/s/**RANDOMLY-GENERATED**/filename.jpg?dl=0

https: //dl.dropbox.com/s/**RANDOMLY-GENERATED**/filename.jpg?dl=0

is there a way I can make it consistent? or control it?
what other hosting site (FREE) that works like this?

**https: //dl.dropbox.com/s/mainfolder-name/subfolder-name/filename.jpg?dl=0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think consistent links are possible with dropbox.
You can use [Internet Archive](https://archive.org). It creates a page for every file that you upload. if file name is unique for archive's database then page url is 
`https://archive.org/details/<filename-without-extension>` 
and you can download it with 
`https://archive.org/download/<filename-without-extension>/<filename>`. It also provides a Rich [API](https://blog.archive.org/developers/).

Note: Only catch here is that use a sufficiently long filename and unique kind of filename